# Google Play: Does Beta Tester See Alpha Updates?

Tags: android, google-play

I know how the process works for Alpha testing an app in Google Play and here is my scenario:

Alpha builds are linked to community A.
Beta builds are linked to community B.

A person (P) happens to be in both groups.

If I release alpha build one today, a beta build tomorrow, and another alpha build the next day, will person P see the latest alpha build, or will they be stuck with the latest beta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a person is in both builds, they will get the Alpha build. [From the docs](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en):

`Please keep in mind that if a user is eligible for both alpha and beta versions, they’ll receive the alpha version.`

Comment: Wow i looked at that doc about a dozen times and completely missed that line. That's what i get for skimming. Thank yoU!